# noob: organizing input fields in wxpython dialogs

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to wxpython so this may be a pretty easy question, I dunno.

I want to have a dialog box pop up that takes user input. Check. I want multiple user input fields. Check. I also want to have them come up in the same line, e.g.:

Enter the Month: *x* Enter the Day: *x* Enter the Hour: *x*

etc... rather than have them each take new lines. So if I have code like this (copied from some tutorial):

```
import wx

class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Text Entry Example', size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1) 
        basicLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Basic Control:")
        basicText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "I've entered some text!", size=(175, -1))
        basicText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        pwdLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Password:")
        pwdText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "password", size=(175, -1),style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=6, vgap=6)
        sizer.AddMany([basicLabel, basicText, pwdLabel, pwdText])
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = TextFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

How would I make it so that the "basic control" and "password" fields appeared on the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the widgets on the same line, then change the number of columns for your sizer from 2 to 4. Or use a horizontally oriented box sizer.